# QGIS on Amazon cloud computing?

Tags: qgis, amazon-web-services

I have a QGIS (2.14.3) viewshed analysis that is taking too long to run on my desktop computer.  Is it possible to run QGIS on the Amazon cloud computing (or some other similar service) to speed up the process?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but you probably want to do an engineering review on your current system, to see if there's a more effective solution available.  Most GIS (and especially raster) performance issues are of an I/O nature, and getting good disk speed from cloud providers can be exorbitantly expensive (far more than an SSD and RAM upgrade on a perfectly adequate PC)

Comment: I have a reasonably robust computer, i7 processor with a 1 TB SSD - yet my analysis has been running for days.  I have no Amazon compute experience, but (perhaps incorrectly) envision uploading my data and letting QGIS on Amazon quickly execute.  Are there documents or web links that would guide me through such an Amazon solution?

Comment: 1Tb SSD or 1Tb HDD? It's hard to imagine what the platform you describe couldn't do in one day. I'm sure the web is filled with Amazon guides, but if you can't positively identify that you have a computer issue for which a cloud platform is a solution, then you may be disappointed.

Comment: Yep, SSD.  The computer even has an NVIDIA GPU.  Welcome to my world!  It's a big project.  Can anyone guide me to documentation on how to run QGIS analysis on Amazon?

Comment: What algorithm ? r.los ?

Comment: You should first and foremost see what is limiting your current PC on doing the process. Different bottlenecks have different solutions. What cloud solutions usually help with are tasks that can be made parallel, but many GIS tasks are difficult to do this with.